# How can I make it easier to get to the sprinkler valves in the future?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I'm digging up my sprinkler valves for what is probably the 3rd time in as many years.  I'm replacing this valve on the right which isn't closing to cut off the water properly.

I dug for about 2 hours through clay and rock to get this far.  And it's 100 degrees outside so I had to stop.

Can I replace these [circular round box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/NDS-6-in-Plastic-Round-Box-with-Overlapping-ICV-Cover-107BC/100377386) with a [big valve box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/NDS-13-in-x-20-in-Standard-Jumbo-Valve-Box-with-ICV-Overlapping-Cover-117BC/100377391)?  The purpose being less digging next time another valve needs to be replaced.  Ideally I could leave these pipes exposed so I don't have to push all this dirt back again.

Are there any other ways to make this job or future jobs easier?  I feel like this setup is a huge mess.  Especially compared to setups I've seen on youtube demonstrations.

[image]

Comment: What are those heavier cables for?

Comment: I don't think there are any heavy cables.  Only small cables wrapped in a big wrapper.

Comment: I was referring to the two wires going into the ground by the pvc pipe. The zoom in fooled me.... just making sure they weren't electric.

Comment: Why don't you put those valves in a box?

Comment: @jwh20 - Sounds like something I should look into.  Can you explain further how to do this and how it will help?

Comment: Does your ground freeze?

Comment: Generally all the valves are in a sprinkler valve box so that they are easy to service and replace.  When you just bury them they are hard to find and you have to dig them up, as you know.  Something like this might help: https://www.homedepot.com/p/DURA-12-in-x-17-in-x-12-in-Deep-Rectangular-Valve-Box-in-Black-Body-Green-Lid-120/203473554?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CG%7CBase%7CAll-Products%7CAll%7CAll%7CPLA%7c71700000014585962%7c58700001236285396%7c92700010802552406&gclid=Cj0KCQjw-b7qBRDPARIsADVbUbVCy0-08F_lB8WdO12aMJqS8vtoXt0_j0T3TjaiIUW8T7jPvQ8rp50aAvWUEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: @jwh20 Ah yes sir!  Now I understand.  yup I am planning to do this for sure!  TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go with the bigger valve box. Also, think about using the compression repair sleeves. It makes the repairs and replacements so much easier and you can use them over and over. Good luck./